# Book about a magical red cape?

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm trying to remember the title of a book I read to my siblings years ago. I have no idea when it was published, but they all remember a magical red cape being central to the story. I also remember it involved a group of friends, and I think one of them was blind.

I remember a scene where they were able to escape somewhere in the dark because the blind girl remembered each of the turns they made earlier. They also remember some sort of rocket or other big machine.

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Did someone say [magical red cape](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ERPHZA4TOOo)?